# Google drive permissions().create() cannot set expiration

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I started looking into Google drive API recently and got confused when trying to [create permissions with expiration date](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html#create).

Generating permissions works fine for me but somehow I cannot assign expiration date to them, which means it ignored 'expirationTime' I provided in the request body and generate one without it.

You may have a look into my code as following:

```
expiration_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
expiration_date_request = expiration_date.isoformat("T") + "Z"
request_body = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'reader',
    "expirationTime": expiration_date_request,
    'emailAddress': email
}
results = service.permissions().create(fileId=file_id, body=request_body, fields = '\
                                   emailAddress,expirationTime,id').execute()
```

So could expert help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Also in my environment, it doesn't work yet. It is considered that it may be a bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760655

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution or workaround for your issue? In my environment, the API doesn't work. But if you want, I would like to try to think of the workaround, although I'm not sure that it is possible to do.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, I tried the following way: I recorded the expiration time into my database and check it say every day.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I had thought that it tries to control the expiration time by a trigger using GAS. Because it is possible to control the permissions using GAS.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the guidelines in using `expirationTime` from the

> [File
>   Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620121/google-drive-permissions-create-cannot-set-expiration)
>
> The time at which this permission will expire (RFC 3339 date-time).
>
> Expiration times have the following restrictions:
>
> - They can only be set on user and group permissions
> - The time must be in the future
> - The time cannot be more than a year in the future

Comment: Could you install ``expirationTime`` in your environment? In my environment, it doesn't work yet. So I'm unable to make a decision whether I should think of a workaround. Your answer will help me decide it.

Comment: As I tried, it does not work even in [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.permissions.create). Though I set `expirationTime` when creating one, I received null about this field of the permission I just created. Have you made it and I did not use it properly?